# Apache2 - It seems that rewrite condition is not always applied

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, browser-refresh

I would like to redirect to /lost/index.php only when the image file does not exists.
When I try it - it seems that it does not work on browser refresh 
If I invoke it with a file which exists on the server

```
/images/image1.jpg
```

- it shows me a file (GOOD - the file exists )
  but if I refresh the browser it redirects me to /lost/index.php (WHICH IS BAD)

Below my rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog      /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*)$    /lost/index.php?image=$1 [L,R]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: It is a bad idea to forward image request to html page. When you use image as `<img src='...'>` browser expects image and not a text. Redirect to the image with text `Not found`

Comment: @Cheery It was just an example, I've change it to index.php - let say that I want to generate this missing picture

Comment: Check what your browser sends in request. Rule looks correct and it should not depend on the refresh. Or, at least, look into the rewrite.log

Comment: My guess would be that your browser cached the redirect at some stage while you were testing, so it is intermittently using the cache to resolve the URL.  I've used a similar configuration with no issues.

Comment: It all works fine if I use %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}. Below is a snippet from doc:
If used in per-server context (i.e., before the request is mapped to the filesystem) SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME cannot contain the full local filesystem path since the path is unknown at this stage of processing. Both variables will initially contain the value of REQUEST_URI in that case. In order to obtain the full local filesystem path of the request in per-server context, use an URL-based look-ahead %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} to determine the final value of REQUEST_FILENAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it.

If you define your rewrite rules inside  element they should look like

```
<Directory /var/www/local.example.com>

        ...
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$    /lost/index.html?image=$1 [R]
</Directory>
```

If you define them "globally" outside the  (per-server context) they should look like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*)$    /lost/index.html?image=$1 [R]
```

This is due the fact that if used in per-server context (i.e., before the request is mapped to the filesystem) SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME cannot contain the full local filesystem path since the path is unknown at this stage of processing. Both variables will initially contain the value of REQUEST_URI in that case. In order to obtain the full local filesystem path of the request in per-server context, use an URL-based look-ahead %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} to determine the final value of REQUEST_FILENAME.

What is also important - the pattern has to be different in both cases. In second case it has to starts with '/' while in the first one not. This is due the fact that REQUEST_FILENAME contains the '/' at the beginning for the second case but it does NOT for the first one